# Is it possible to manipulate retrofit url without method parameter?

Tags: retrofit

Network call are made like this

```
@GET("/api/video/{slug}/show")
    void getVideoData(@Path("slug") String slug,Callback<VideoContainerGSON>cb);
```

Now I need to add wariable path before "/api" e.g:

```
/en/api/video/{slug}/show
```

Or

```
/sp/video/{slug}/show
```

That parameter is global wide, so without setting alteration all network call will use same language path.
Question: Is there a way to alter it without method signature or I must change method signature to

```
@GET("/{lang}/api/video/{slug}/show")
        void getVideoData(@Path("lang") String lang, @Path("slug") String slug,Callback<VideoContainerGSON>cb);
```

Comment: Do you use this in Android?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string xmls to resolve your issue. You can put your api root in string.xml and override it in other xmls for example:

- in **values/string.xml**

  `<string name="api_root">http://yourapiroot.com/en</string>`
- in **values-es/string.xml**

  `<string name="api_root">http://yourapiroot.com/sp</string>`

and when you create your adapter set api root from resources as is shown in the code below:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint(context.getString(R.string.api_root))
.build()
```

if you do not want to make the rest api from device language you can set params which defines language in api root in method where you build `RestAdapter`

And after that you start your paths from `/api/...` For example:

```
   @GET("/api/video/{slug}/show")
    void getVideoData(@Path("slug") String slug,Callback<VideoContainerGSON>cb);
```